# Swift : Track group of API calls to show progress bar

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiontask

I have collection view with 6 cells - each cell makes 3-4 different API calls .
I want to show collective progress bar below navigation bar .
How to keep track of api calls to generate progress from them ?
PS: API calls don't have any download or upload task .

Comment: You should be able simply update a counter each time an api call finishes

Comment: create a queue for these calls then you can simply check the count of the elements of queue and show progress bar

Comment: any example links ?